# PHP - Запись в файл в многопользовательском режиме

Tags: php, flock

Записываю протокол событий вот таким скриптом:

```
<?php
$trnum = $_REQUEST['x'];
$file=fopen("track.log",'a');
flock($file,2);
fputs($file,"$trnum \t" . date("Y-m-d h:ia") . "\n");
flock($file,3);
fclose($file);
?>
```

Но возникает вопрос:
Что будет, если вызовов будет слишком много и со всех сторон?
Не выйдет ли, что пока я залочил файл в одном вызове скрипта, другой тоже попытался, ругнулся и ничего не записал?
Как предусмотреть это в коде?

Comment: Все нормально будет, но, достаточно медленно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция **flock()** создает для файла флаг, указывающий на то, что с файлом идет работа. При этом другой скрипт или другая программа, **умеющая распознавать подобный флаг**, сделает соответствующие выводы и содержимого файла не нарушит.

По умолчанию, данная функция будет ждать получения **эксклюзивной блокировки на запись**, это поведение можно изменить с помощью параметра LOCK_NB. Если у Вас будет многопоточная запись в файл, то каждый следующий запрос просто будет дольше выполняться из-за наличия блокировки.

Кстати, весь ваш код можно перенести в одну конструкцию:

```
file_put_contents('track.log', "$trnum \t" . date("Y-m-d h:ia") ."\n", LOCK_EX | FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Ух-ты! Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

> Что будет, если вызовов будет слишком много и со всех сторон?

flock реализует механизм блокировки - синхронизации, при которой все, кто хочет завладеть ресурсом и превышают некоторую квоту (определяемую типом блокировки), просто ожидают в очереди до тех пор, пока ресурс не освободится.

Поэтому в данном случае доступ к файлу будет синхронизирован, и запись в файл будет вестись только одним процессом, а все остальные будут ожидать освобождения блокировки.